# Assembly directive .extern use in uclibc-gcc

Tags: assembly, arm, extern, uclinux

I try to use a variable defined in .c file in a .S program.

In .c file:

```
const int var = 10;
```

While in .S file:

```
    .extern var
LDR lr, _VAR
_VAR: .word var
```

It can be compiled. But when executing, there is error msg "Can't modify application's text section; use the GCC option -fPIE for position-independent executables."

The cross compile tool is arm-v7-linux-uclibceabi-gcc. And the target is ARM cortex R4.

Can't the ".extern" be used like this?

Thanks,
Simmis.

Comment: Which chip are you using ? What microprocessor ? MIPS ? ARM ? PIC ? Freescale ? Atmel ?

Comment: ARM cortex R4. ST chipset.

Comment: Strongly suggest that you include that detail in the body of your message; also, add a tag about it as well. Right now you have tags of "Assembly" and "Extern".  I encourage you to also add ARM and cortex

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write to that variable? Perhaps in assembly? It's read-only data, and presumably the linker script has put it in the text section - so you can't write to it.

Comment: No. Just using ldr to fetch var.